# Using middleware to convert responses to pdf

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a middleware that will convert the response from endpoints tagged with a custom attribute to pdf.  I'm using IronPdf and it looks something like this:

```
public class PdfRendererMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public PdfRendererMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
        var attribute = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<PdfRenderableAttribute>();
        if ((attribute != null) && 
            (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK))
        {
            var pdfRenderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

            // Get response body as string
            context.Response.Body.Position = 0;
            var rawRequestBody = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();

            // Convert to pdf
            var pdf = pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(rawRequestBody);
            var pdfBinary = pdf.BinaryData;
            
            // Write the new body
            await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(pdfBinary, 0, pdfBinary.Length);
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception on `context.Response.Body.Position = 0;` because `Specified method is not supported`.

When I looked at other examples of how to read and rewrite the response body, this seemed to be the correct way to do it.

How do I rewrite the body of a response in middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public class PdfRendererMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public PdfRendererMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
        var attribute = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<PdfRenderableAttribute>();
        if ((attribute != null) && (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK))
        {
            var pdfRenderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();

            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;

                    await _next(context);

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);


                    var pdf = pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(responseBody);
                    //pdf.SaveAs("output.pdf");
                    var pdfBinary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseBody); //pdf.BinaryData;
                    await originalBody.WriteAsync(pdfBinary, 0, pdfBinary.Length);
                }

            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;
            }
        }
        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

When I use `var pdfBinary = pdf.BinaryData;` it is garbled:
[image]

I guess it should be caused by the conversion of pdf generated by `IronPdf` to `byte`.